# Az Powershell commands not working for "Cloud service (classic)"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services

I'm simply trying to extract the below information using Az PowerShell.
[Resource on portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBM0n.png)

Already tried the below commands

```
Get-AzCloudService -ResourceGroupName "testCosmosDB" # it gives no result.
Get-AzCloudService -ResourceGroupName "testCosmosDB" -CloudServiceName "testnameon" # as shown below.
```

[image: 2nd command o/p]

Comment: Have you selected your subscription? `Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<subscriotion-id>" | Set-AzContext`, ou you can add `-SubscriptionId` to `Get-AzCloudService`

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, no problem with subscription context or authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `Az` PowerShell module only support Cloud Services (Extended Support) and not Cloud Services (Classic).

One option for you is to migrate your classic Cloud Services to Cloud Services (Extended Support). You can learn more about the migration here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/overview#migration-to-azure-resource-manager.

Another option (not sure if it is even viable) is to make use of really old version of Azure PowerShell (even before AzureRM) which has support for classic resources.

Comment: so in this case all commands mentioned here are for Cloud Service(Extended Support) and not for Cloud Service (Classic)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cloudservice/?view=azps-6.4.0#cloud-services

Comment: That is correct. Please see this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/sample-get-cloud-service. HTH.

Comment: In this case Azure Service Management PowerShell module should be used : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/servicemanagement/install-azure-ps?view=azuresmps-4.0.0 (ASM model == Classic)